# asp:TreeView in asp:UpdatePanel - Bad page performance - doing full page PostBacks!

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax

Hello I have a problem with asp:TreeView in asp:UpdatePanel
Would you please tell me what to do ?

I have several updatepanels in my web project, and all of them declared as: 
… UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" …

When I put an asp:treeview control into an updatepanel it makes the whole page become slower, much slower.

Yes the treeview content is not very small, and I use recursion for filling it, but I do it on the page_load and only once: if(!Page.IsPostBack){ FillTreeView(…); }

When I do not call FillTreeView() method, ie I do not use TreeView it’s all works fine. I have a search part in my page, implemented in another UpdatePanel, and it works very fast with max speed of 12-30 Kb/s,  but with the TreeView load it reaches to 250-400 Kb/s.

Actually, the treeview implemented in updatepanel, restrains my web page, doing full page postbacks every time I do Any kind of action with the page, even if I don’t touch the treeview at all - when I use my search, which is absolutely nothing to do with it, not connected to treeview in no manner.

My dear friends, collegues, programmers, help me please with your good and usefull advices, thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to skip the update panels and write you own Ajax request with web services and jQuery. By using the update panel you do loose control of what´s being sent and its a lot sometimes

See this [Link](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)